# Batch file search and replace using wildcards?

Tags: javascript

Batch file search and replace using wildcards

I have a html (txt) file I am using as a template or sourcefile to create 
further html files.  Filename = pg_0001.htm and it contains a line of code 
thus:

pg_0001.jpg

I want to parse the pg_0001.htm sourcefile, increment and replace the jpeg 
string, like this:  "pg_0002.jpg", and then output the edited 
htm file to a new filename pg_0002.htm

I then take each newly created file (pg_0002.htm, pg_0003.htm etc) as the 
sourcefile and repeat the processing until I have reached my target goal (let's 
say 100 newly created htm files containing code to display the corresponding 
jpeg.

It must be done this way (fileX.htm containing fileX.jpg) because there is 
other javascript that uses these incremented filenames as function input.

I used to know how to write incrementing batch files many years ago but I'm 
old & very rusty now.  Can anyone please help me do this?  Many 
thanks in advance.

regards Harry

Comment: Javascript can not write to file.

Comment: Yes it can Nick,
Use an ActiveXObject.
I'll answer my own question now for others to benefit.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out eventually.  Built 250 pages with THIS little javascript gem.  Started by building the filename with zeroes padding. Build the HTML markup for the new files by concatenating strings. Put the lot in a  write loop to increment the filenames etc...

fso  = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

firstfile = 1;
lastfile = 250;

a = firstfile;
do
{

```
    var titlestr = new String("pg_");
    var strnewswf = new String("pg_");
    var strnewfile = new String("pg_");
    var szFileNum = new String(a);
    var szFileNumLen = 4 - szFileNum.length;
    for (i = 0; i < szFileNumLen; i++)
         strnewfile += "0";
    titlestr = strnewfile + szFileNum;
    strnewswf = strnewfile + szFileNum + ".jpg";     
    strnewfile = strnewfile + szFileNum + ".htm";

    var fh = fso.CreateTextFile("E:\\"+strnewfile, true);
```

HTMLstring='\n';
HTMLstring+='\n';
HTMLstring+='\n';
HTMLstring+=''+titlestr+'\n';
HTMLstring+='\n';

//.........more markup here..........

HTMLstring+='\n';

```
    fh.write(HTMLstring);


    fh.Close(); 
    a++;
```

}
while (a <= lastfile)